# Setting linkedcell of multi-option field

Tags: excel, vba, radio-button

I have an Excel sheet with quite a few groups of option buttons (inserted from form controls and grouped using group boces). What is the easiest way to set the linked cell of each group using VBA code? I tried

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range("test").Select
.LinkedCell = Range("A1")
```

but it had no effect. "test" is the name I set for one of the option buttons in the corresponding group.

(The reason for trying to set the LinkedCell via VBA is that these links are sometimes lost for reasons I don't yet understand. If anyone can point out a possible scenario how this could possibly happen in the first place, I would be very grateful.)

Comment: @ionizing: "Run-time error ‘438′: Object would not assist this property or methodology"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a named range will only point to one or more cells on a worksheet. It does not refer to a form control. You're likely using a Form Control Option Button somewhere on your worksheet. The code to set the `LinkedCell` property is

```
Dim optButton As Shape
Set optButton = Sheet2.Shapes("Option Button 2")
optButton.ControlFormat.LinkedCell = "H4"
```